# Slow WiFi (atheros QCA9377) speed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, atheros, download-speed

After I upgrade from 18.04LTS to 20.04LTS my wifi speed droped with 90% from ~400Mb to ~40Mb/sec.
Even with the live usb I have obtained the same results.

I have checked if the ath10k driver is loaded and it is.
I turned off the power management, tryed to remove the backport-iwlwifi-dkms but is not installed. 
I have changed antenna with ant_sel=1 or ant_sel=2.
Disabled hw encryption.
Nothing seems to work...

On windows and ubuntu 18.04lts everything went ok. I have encountered the same behavior on Debian 10.
It is very odd that the link speed/bit rate is only 6Mb/s and doesn't seems to change in any way even if I force it to 54Mb or else.
It can be something kernel related?

Any solution or it will be fixed in a short time?

HW: atheros QCA9377 on i7 Asus Laptop connected to Asus RT AC3200 trough 5ghz band WPA2

I really love the new look and feel of the ubuntu 20.04 but this issue makes me to think at a fresh install of 18.04.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you set `ant_sel` from Realtek, or do soemthing with Intel drivers if you have an Atheros device?

Comment: I suspect it is something incorrect with Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter and Asus RT AC3200. I recently changed router to Asus RT AC3200 from Asus N18U and upload speed droped to 500KB/s from 5MB/s whilst DL is stil around 10MB/S. Signal is quite good -60dBm. I have not changed anything except router, so I am using Ubuntu 18.04LTS . This is strange because DL/UP speed was on acceptable level before change. I am still searching for solution but no luck.

Comment: Very strange. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 since I have encountered this problem, but I will also check for solutions or updates. Thanks for your response!

Comment: For the moment I've found an workaround but it's just makes the wi-fi having the right speed but after a while it drops the connection. So it's not a stable fix or something but maybe you can found out what its causing this issue. With this commands I can set the wi-fi to its full speed [ sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci && sudo modprobe ath10k_pc ] after reloading the module... So what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have found that resetting the kernal module 'fixs' the problem. Your mileage my vary. I run this after first logging in after the wifi connection has been established.

$  sudo modprobe -r ath10k_pci

$  sudo modprobe ath10k_pci

Comment: This one works for my Linux mint 21.1, ubuntu 22.04, the `iw` link speed is still the same, rx bitrate: 433.3 MBit/s tx bitrate: 6.0 MBit/s, but real speed test result is much better.